# Problem when writing a loop for a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement

I have a dataframe with two columns 'ENTRYP' and 'Status'. If the value of ENTRYP is less than or equal to 0.02, it should change the 'status' to 'ENT_EXT'. Every time it crosses that range it should add count to the Status. For example: movement1, ent_ext1, movement2, ent_Ext2. I have written the below code but it is throwing the below error

**The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()**

```
h_count = 0
current = "ENT_EXT"
current == "MOVING"

status_halt = []

for idx in df2.index:
    if (df2["ENTRYP"][idx] <= 0.02):
        if current == "MOVING":
            h_count += 1
        status_halt.append(f"ENT_EXT{h_count}")
        current = "ENT_EXT"
    elif (df2["ENTRYP"][idx] > 0.02):
        if current == "ENT_EXT":
            m_count += 1
        status_halt.append(f"MOVING_{m_count}")
        current = "MOVING"

df2["Status"] = status_halt
```

I have added the snippet of the dataframe and required output.

Please let me know how to proceed https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0Qsj.png

Comment: Add sample data in your question

Answer (score 0):

I think I get what you need, although the function to obtain it it's a bit complicated.
I explain my code in the comments for the case with values less equal to 0.02, but for cases bigger than 0.02 the logic is exactly the same.

```
import pandas as pd
a=[0.04, 0.04, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01]
adf=pd.DataFrame(a, columns=["ENTRYP"])

def afunct(ent):
    stats=["MOVEMENT_","ENT_EXT"]
    c_status=[]
    m_counter=0
    e_counter=0
    for i in ent:
        if(i <= 0.02): # cases when the value is less equal that 0.02 (it's ENT_EXT")
            if(len(c_status)==0): # if the list is empty we initialize the counters for "M" and "E" and put the first STATUS
                m_counter=0
                e_counter=1
                c_status.append("{}{}".format(stats[1],e_counter ))
            elif(c_status[-1][0]=="E"):  ## if the last status is a "E" we just add another "ENT_EXT"
                c_status.append("{}{}".format(stats[1],e_counter ))
            elif(c_status[-1][0]=="M"): # if the last status is a "M" we add to the e_counter and assign STATUS
                e_counter+=1
                c_status.append("{}{}".format(stats[1],e_counter ))
        elif(i>0.02):
            if(len(c_status)==0):
                m_counter=1
                e_counter=0
                c_status.append("{}{}".format(stats[0],m_counter ))
            elif(c_status[-1][0]=="M"):
                c_status.append("{}{}".format(stats[0],m_counter ))
            elif(c_status[-1][0]=="E"):
                m_counter+=1
                c_status.append("{}{}".format(stats[0],m_counter ))
    return(c_status)

adf["STATUS"]=afunct(adf["ENTRYP"])
```

Results:

```
    ENTRYP  STATUS
0   0.04    MOVEMENT_1
1   0.04    MOVEMENT_1
2   0.02    ENT_EXT1
3   0.02    ENT_EXT1
4   0.03    MOVEMENT_2
5   0.03    MOVEMENT_2
6   0.02    ENT_EXT2
7   0.01    ENT_EXT2
```